# Android's listview. Update view within of of the cells just after invalidating Activity's view

Tags: android, listview

I have ListViewActivity

```
public class SelectActivity extends ListActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_one_of);
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            createChildList(),
            R.layout.select_one_of_childrow, 
            new String[] { KEY_VALUE },
            new int[] { R.id.selectoneof_add_new_item});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
// ...
}
```

after setListAdapter() calls I would like to execute the following code:

```
((TextView) getListView().getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.selectoneof_add_new_item)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ticked, 0);
```

but getListView().getChildAt(xxx) returns null and I catch NullPointerException. Where should I put mentioned above code-snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where should I put mentioned above
>   code-snippet?

Nowhere. Instead, write a custom `ListAdapter` and customize your rows that way. [Here is a free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that demonstrates the general technique.

Comment: I don't believe this! I still hope that it can be done simply without writing own/custom ListAdapter

Comment: IMHO, "writing own/custom ListAdapter" is simpler and more reliable than what you are proposing.

Comment: ... But  I don't want to do check during each listView rendering ... I need to do that on once on Activity's start ...

Comment: I found that listView.postInvalidate() calls when everything is being invaludated. Is it possible to override this method?

Comment: Thank you, guy! I found that when list has big amount of data and I would scroll this list, I have to call "setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()" for each elements in any case to avoid 'strange' behavior.
Sorry I didn't believe to before :)